# Python: is there a way to implement break into a function that is meant to be looped?

Tags: python, loops, class

I have a class function that updates class instance parameters when a specific condition is met. It looks something like this:

```
def step_k(self):

        if probability > self.epsilon:

            self.k_dps = np.append(self.k_dps, new_dps)

            self.k += 1

            self.update_pdf()
```

It is meant to be used in a loop up until the point where the condition is no longer fulfilled. I tried using 'break' in the hopes it would also work when executed in a function

```
def step_k(self):

        if probability > self.epsilon:

            self.k_dps = np.append(self.k_dps, new_dps)

            self.k += 1

            self.update_pdf()
        else:
            break
```

but it doesn't. `probability` is calculated in the class so I can't just pull the condition out. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `break` is only allowed syntactically in the loop itself. Your function has to return a value which the caller can use to determine whether to execute a `break` statement or not.